# Is there a place you can download the install files for AutoCAD LT 2008 (or other old versions of software)

Tags: autocad

I recently lost my installation CD for AutoCAD LT 2008

I think i may be able to recover my license info, so now i'm wondering if there is somewhere you can download the installer from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the latest LT version (2012 as of today), but not earlier versions.

You've got two options:

- Contact Autodesk support and ask for some way to get the AutoCAD LT 2008 installer files.
- Use a P2P or other file sharing method to download a copy of the installer, and use your license credentials.